# Azure Devops Server unable to connect to Service Hooks behind proxy

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

We're having trouble configure Azure Devops Server to post to Service Hook externally. What we've tried:

- Setting proxy server on Service Account
- Retried, reapplied account
- Restarted iis
- Set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment vars

Still getting this

```
There was an error sending the request, so there was no response.  
Error(s):
    An error occurred while sending the request.
    Unable to connect to the remote server
    A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 143.204.245.159:443

Be sure there are no firewall rules blocking requests going out to the endpoint selected.
```

Are there any other ways to configer proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. These settings worked in my environment.

Local Group Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Make proxy settings per-machine

I selected 'Enabled'

I Launched Internet Explorer as administrator and change proxy settings.